# Updating average rating on new table entry with a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to calculate the new average(in the movie table) every time a new tuple is inserted in the watch table
I have thought of creating a new table inside the trigger, creating a for loop to count the average as well as declaring a new table variable, none of which work for me

This is what I currently have

```
    Create OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_avg
    FOR INSERT ON WATCH
    COMPOUND TRIGGER
        avg_c   REAL;
        counter INTEGER :=0;
    BEFORE EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN

        SELECT AVG(rating) INTO avg_c FROM ??? WHERE :NEW.movie_ID = movie_ID;
    END BEFORE EACH ROW;
    AFTER EACH ROW IS 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Movie SET avg_rating = avg_c WHERE :NEW.movie_ID = movie_ID;
    END AFTER EACH ROW;
END;
/
```

Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing an average over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the average, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with the usual stackoverflow answer, however, I need to update the average with a trigger. Any info on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this; use a view or a query as necessary.

---

However, as an academic exercise. Create a type that can be used in SQL queries:

```sql
CREATE TYPE id_list IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
```

Then track the updated movies and then after the statement has completed the update all the movies with the ratings:

```sql
Create OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_avg
FOR INSERT ON WATCH
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  movies id_list := id_list();
AFTER EACH ROW
IS
BEGIN
  movies.EXTEND;
  movies(movies.COUNT) := :NEW.movie_id;
END AFTER EACH ROW;
AFTER STATEMENT
IS 
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO Movie dst
  USING (
    SELECT movie_id,
           AVG(rating) AS rating
    FROM   watch
    WHERE  movie_id MEMBER OF movies
    GROUP BY movie_id
  ) src
  ON (dst.movie_id = src.movie_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET avg_rating = src.rating;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6f30b41534594d4002da5c066925dcb6)*